# Regex to fail email domain with two consecutive dots

Tags: regex

I am trying to validate the domain part of an email and I want to check that there is NOT two consecutive dots in the domain i.e. the following are not valid

- joe@ms..com
- joe@ms.com..uk
- joe@..ms.com
- joe@ms.com.au..

I have the regex to find it

```
@+\.{2}|@.+\.{2}
```

but I am using an Regex attribute in .NET and want to build the regex that is valid (i.e. one dots) not the one that fails

I thought the `^` character meant

> everything that is NOT the expression

so I thought that `^(@+\.{2}|@.+\.{2})` would have worked but it does not nor does the .NET framework `EmailAddress` Attribute  - it stops `joe@ms..com` but does not stop `joe@ms.com..au`

Comment: `^` outside of character class means start of string. `^` as first character inside character class means everything except the characters in the character class.

Comment: tried @+[^\.]{2}|@.+[^\.]{2} and also @+[^\.\.]|@.+[^\.\.]  and those did not work...is that what you meant?

Comment: No, I'm just telling you the meaning of the syntax. The way you use it is wrong. It only checks that there are 2 non-dot characters after `@`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **negative lookahead** in front of your regex:

```
@(?!.*?\.\.)[^@]+$
```

Which will fail the match if 2 consecutive dots are present in domain anywhere.

`[^@]` will match 1 or more characters that are not `@`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qI5kW8/1)

Comment: Does it works if there are more than 2 consecutive dots before the "com" domain?

Comment: Any where after `@` it will block