# regex works in online regex tester but not in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex

the following [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oM7eF9/1) works just fine online but not when I attempt to run it in c#/.NET

```
 var regex = new RegularExpressionAttribute(@"@(?!.*?\.\.)[^@]+$");
 Assert.IsTrue(regex.IsValid("bob@bob.com"));
```

here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814935/regex-to-fail-email-domain-with-two-consecutive-dots) to post that will explain the regex and what I am trying to do

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? validating the email?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [RegularExpressionAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx) requires a full match of the string.

In your case, you are only matching starting at the `@` character, so you start somewhere in between of your string. This is just not good enough for the RegularExpressionAttribute. You can think of it adding an implicit `^` at the start to your expression (and an implicit `$` at the end too, so you can drop that as well).

So to fix this, you need to make sure that it has something to match at the start to, e.g. a `.*?`:

```
new RegularExpressionAttribute(@".*?@(?!.*?\.\.)[^@]+");
```

And then it works. You don’t need any other regular expression flags.

---

Unfortunately, this behavior of `RegularExpressionAttribute` is mentioned nowhere in the documentation. You can verify it in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/RegularExpressionAttribute.cs,57) however:

```
// We are looking for an exact match, not just a search hit. This matches what
// the RegularExpressionValidator control does
return (m.Success && m.Index == 0 && m.Length == stringValue.Length);
```

So it’s technically not an added `^` and `$` but after finding a match, the start and end index are required to match the string’s start and end index (which is essentially the same thing).

And if you think about it, this behavior makes a lot of sense for validation. After all, you want to make sure that a string matches a certain full-specified format, and not just check if some substring is valid.

Comment: thanks....yes this does work....don't know why it was down voted..it's the solution

Comment: Might as well drop the trailing `$` too.

Comment: Could you please provide a quote from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx where it is stated that the full match is required?

Comment: @stribizhev Unfortunately, I can’t since there simply isn’t something I could quote. I added some proof based on the reference source however (in case the practical proof isn’t enough).